# Where to put the image file for CFBundleTypeIconFiles in iOS?

Tags: ios, cfbundledocumenttypes

I want to inform iOS that my app can open pdf file, I follow this guide [Importing Documents](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/importing-exporting-documents-ios) the importing document part, but I need to add an icon for my app in `CFBundleDocumentTypes`, I add a key named `CFBundleTypeIconFiles` and its type is array, I add a string for example "myIcon.png", but I don't know where to put the myIcon.png file, can anybody help?

Comment: you can use assets.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I've tried using assets, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The guide that you are following is using a pretty old version of iOS and Xcode but assuming you are on an updated version there should be an AppAssets.xcassets catalog created in your folder structure that you can put all your images/icons in, you should be able to access them from there.

[Here is a link to apple documentation about asset catalogs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/)